# Array.prototype without modifying original array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a new Array method without modifying the original array.

```
my_array.push('foo') //modifies my_array
my_array.slice(2) //returns a new array without modifying my_array
```

I'd like to make a new Array.prototype method that returns an array without modifying the array it was called upon. So this would be possible:

```
//[define new method here] Array.prototype.add_foo = function() {...
var my_array = ['poo'];

my_array.add_foo(); //would return ['poo', 'foo'];
my_array; //would return ['poo'];
```

Comment: Just clone the array first.

Comment: Okay, create a new array and return it instead of modifying `this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Array.prototype.add_foo = function(){
    var ret = this.slice(0); //make a clone
    ret.push("foo"); //add the foo
    return ret; //return the modified clone
}
```

Comment: Simpler: `return this.concat('foo')`

Comment: @elclanrs : Good. I've never used/spotted .concat. Thx

Comment: For some reason I had the impression I could only return a modified version of the original array and not a new instance of Array. thanks

Answer (score 10):

```
my_array.concat('foo');
```

`concat` doesn't alter the original array.